# EntityDataSource Where?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, entitydatasource

I have a entitydatasource connecting to my database and I want to filter the results using the "Where" property. As a test I have the following:

```
it.CustomerID is not 6
```

And I get the following error:

```
The query syntax is not valid. Near term '6', line 6, column 25.
```

I guess what I'm typing in is wrong, but why?

Comment: Possibly use `!=` or `&lt;&gt;` instead of `is not`?

Answer (score 0):

Usage of the "Where" property follows the Entity SQL language. So, i think that right syntax is:

```
it.CustomerID != 6
```

or

```
it.CustomerID <> 6
```

Entity SQL Reference - "Not Equal To" Operator: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb399278(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Remove 'is not' to != and make sure that we can't write any function on EntityDataSource like upper(), lower().. etc but you can do it as Linq query